# Excel to PDF but dynamic form not static

Tags: acrobat

I am able to convert excel to pdf and have pdf recognize the fields for form purposes. However, acrobat xi saves the form as static and not dynamic. How do I save this form as Dynamic form?

Comment: And how usage of specific office software is related to programming?

Comment: I have bunch of code that I need to put behind the PDF dynamic form. There are series of steps before I can do that. steps are convert xls to pdf, make fields recognized by acrobat, save the pdf as dynamic and this is where I am having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go. The most flexible and obvious is to use a LiveCycle form. If you have an Acrobat Professional version 7 to X, then you can use LiveCycle Designer.

You can find more details explained here:

http://www.pdfscripting.com/public/department48.cfm